# Accounting Area51 proposal has been deleted

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I noticed that in the help center article [What topics can I ask about here?](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), the list of topics that are off topic includes:

> - Questions about accounting that are academic or have no bearing on personal finance ([Area 51 proposal for an Accounting site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82671/accounting?referrer=7pfmR-WhFdrRGB--mP_CgA2))

However, the linked Area51 proposal has been deleted:

> This proposal has been deleted.
>
> Inactive proposals that do not receive any activity for one month are subject to deletion. Occasionally, proposals may be removed from Area 51 for reasons of moderation: spam, off topic, abuse, etc. For more information, see the [FAQ](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).

**I believe the link to the *Accounting* proposal should be removed from the help center article.**

Comment: new link: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102473/accounting?referrer=OHV9LElnSZmDODMqVrDIpg2

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Deleted again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Done. I didn't know accounting site was killed. The link is now gone.
Thank you for bringing it to our attention.

Comment: Does this mean accounting questions are fair game here now? Or is this site restricted to strictly "personal" finance?

Comment: @curious_cat Personally I think that should be a different question altogether. The purpose of my "question" was largely just to draw a moderator's attention to the fact that the help center article needed to be updated.

Comment: @curious_cat The only result of this question was to remove a broken link on the help page.  The scope of this site has not changed because of this.

Comment: Accounting questions that are PF are still on topic here. Business accounting still isn't .